# The return property of exclamation in front of array

Tags: theming

I am learning the drupal 7 by the example module. 
In the render_example, I don't understand the usage of the exclamation mark (!) in front of the !array and !alter.

I am sure that it is not related to the "boolean" nor "negation". 
Please kindly advise how can I find the detail of the usage.

```
function render_example_info() {
  return t('The render example provides a <ul><li><a href="!arrays">demonstration of of render array usage</a></li><li><a href="!alter">using hook_page_alter()</a> to make various changes on a page.</li></ul>', array('!arrays' => url('examples/render_example/arrays'), '!alter' => url('examples/render_example/altering')));
```

}

When I edit the "!array" to "$array",

```
function render_example_info() {
return t('The render example provides a <ul><li><a href="$arrays">demonstration of of render array usage</a></li><li><a href="!alter">using hook_page_alter()</a> to make various changes on a page.</li></ul>', array('$arrays' => url('examples/render_example/arrays'), '!alter' => url('examples/render_example/altering')));
```

}

the message was changed
from: 
demonstration of of render array usage  
(with hyper link "http://www.example.com/drupal/?q=examples/render_example/arrays"
to:
/drupal/?q=examples/render_example/arrays">demonstration of of render array usage
(with hyper link "http://www.example.com/drupal/&5cem&nbspclass=" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) uses [format_string()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7), which uses [strtr()](http://php.net/strtr). For this reason, your second example snippet works. Since `format_str()` is using the following code, any token that starts with a character different from *!*, *%*, or *@* is treated as if the token started with *%*.

```
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key[0]) {
      case '@':
        // Escaped only.
        $args[$key] = check_plain($value);
        break;

      case '%':
      default:
        // Escaped and placeholder.
        $args[$key] = drupal_placeholder($value);
        break;

      case '!':
        // Pass-through.
    }
  }
```

[drupa_placeholder()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_placeholder/7) is the responsible for escaping some characters, since it calls [check_plain()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7).

```
function drupal_placeholder($text) {
  return '<em class="placeholder">' . check_plain($text) . '</em>';
}
```

As side note, since `$arrays` is inside a single-quote string, PHP doesn't replace it with the value of the `$arrays` string. If you wanted to put the content of a string into the string passed to `t()`, you should use a `t()`-placeholder, which starts with *!*, *%*, or *@*.

Comment: Thank very much. I had check the function check_plan() and drupal_placeholder().